# angular 2+ iframe src reverse proxy

Tags: angular

I have an iframe inside my angular app and I'm trying to change its src attribute depending on which environnement my app is running on.
So I want to do that using a reverse proxy(with the proxy.conf.json), I don't no exactly how?

Note that the iframe' src change everytimme an action take place in the app.

So if anyone have an answer or an example?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

I needed same thing and only way I found to change iframe src was through nativeElement.

So in your .html file your iframe need a id through #:

`<iframe #myIframe  ></iframe>`

In your component you get reference to iframe with @ViewChild like bellow:

`@ViewChild('myIframe') myIframe: ElementRef;`

If you use up Angular 8:

`@ViewChild('myIframe', {static: false}) myIframe: ElementRef;`

So to change src you need change it on nativeElement :

`this.myIframe.nativeElement.src = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js';`

Works fine for me, I hope helped!